# Singular Value Decomposition - what do I have to do?

Tags: operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, svd

Show that the Singular Value Decomposition of

$$
T\colon L^2([0,1])\to H^1([0,1]), x\mapsto\int\limits_0^t x(s)\, ds
$$

is given by

$$
\sigma_j=\frac{1}{(j-1/2)\pi}, v_j(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos((j-1/2)\pi x), u_j(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin((j-1/2)\pi x).
$$

---

I do not know what i have to do here.
Do I "only" have to calculate that

$Tu_j=\sigma_j v_j$

and that

$T^* v_j=\sigma_j u_j$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Finding an SVD means having *complete* sets of left- and right- singular vectors. So you should also check that  $(u_j)$ is a basis of $L^2$  and $(v_j)$ is a basis of $H^1$.

Comment: Okay. And do i have to show that $\sigma_j^2$ are Eigenvalues auf $T^*T$?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a mistake in the text? If i try to show $Tu_j(x)=\sigma_jv_j(x)$ i always get $\sigma_j\sqrt{2}(1-\cos((j-1/2)\pi x)$ for the left side and this is not equal to $\sigma_jv_j(x)$! Maybe it should be $v_j(x)=\sqrt{2}(1-\cos((j-1/2)\pi x)$ in the text?

Comment: @math I don't think you should consider $T^*T$ here. Formally, $T*Tu_j=T^*(\sigma_j u_j)=\sigma_j^2 u_j$ follows from the properties $Tu_j=\sigma_j u_j$ and $T^* v_j = \sigma_j u_j$. However, it is unnatural to identify the dual of $H^1$ with the space $H^1$ itself. One usually thinks of $(H^1)^*$ as a different Hilbert space, $H^{-1}$. With this interpretation the composition $T^*T$ is not meaningful. // Yes, it looks like $u_j$ should be corrected.

Comment: Now it is the question whether $u_j(x)$ or $v_j(x)$ is wrong in the text.

Comment: @math12 Or maybe they are both correct, they are just switched around. It looks like $Tv_j=\sigma_j u_j$ and $T^* u_j = \sigma_j v_j$.

Comment: $Tv_j=\sigma_j u_j$ is correct. But $T^*u_j=\sigma_jv_j$, too? I cannot show that. The adjoint operator $T^*$ is given by $x\mapsto\int\limits_t^1 x(s)\, ds+x'(t)$. When calculating $T^*u_j(x)$ i get $T^*u_j(x)=\sigma_j v_j(x)-\sqrt{2}\cos((j-1/2)\pi)+v_j(x)\cdot (j-1/2)\pi$. *confused*

Comment: More precisely I get: $T^*u_j(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(j-1/2)\pi}\left[-\cos((j-1/2)\pi)+\cos((j-1/2)\pi x)\right] + v_j(x)\frac{1}{\sigma_j}$ and I do not see that this is equal to $\sigma_jv_j(x)$. Can you help me, pls?

Comment: @math12 I think $x'(t)$ should not be in $T^*$. It would make the operator unbounded. The adjoint of integral operator with kernel $K(x,y)$ is the integral operator with kernel $\overline{K(y,x)}$.

Comment: Then the origin of my problem is this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275783/find-adjoint-operator-of-an-operator-t?rq=1  I thought i was right and one user did say so, too. Do you find my mistake there (if you like to)?

Comment: @math12 Nevermind, I keep forgetting that your operator goes into $H^1$, not into $L^2$. But if it goes into $H^1$, then it's not compact. I'm confused too.

Comment: Very strange ;(

Comment: And what can I do now?!

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in the text and that the given SVD belongs to the operator $S\colon L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1]), x\mapsto\int\limits_0^t x(s)\, ds$ which has the adjoint operator given by $x\mapsto\int\limits_t^1 x(s)\, ds$. Then the identities $Sv_j=\sigma_ju_j$ and $S^*u_j=\sigma_jv_j$ are indeed correct. What do I have to show additionally?

Comment: @math12 As I said in the answer, the other thing to show is that $u_j$ and $v_j$ are bases for $L^2$.

Comment: When looking at my notes I have to show, that $\left\{v_j\right\}$ is a ONB für $ker(S)^{\bot}$ and that $\left\{u_j\right\}$ is a ONB for $\overline{rg(T)}$.

Comment: Both $T$ and $T*$ (or do you call them $S$ and $S^*$ now?) have trivial kernel. Since the kernel of $T^*$ is trivial, the range of $T$ is dense. Which means you do need those systems of vectors to be bases for $L^2$.

Comment: Yes, I now call it $S$ and $S^*$. My explanation of the situation  is the following: $K=S^*S$ is a compact operator. Therefore the spectralsentence says: $L^2([0,1])=ker(K)\oplus \overline{\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,...)}$. Because $ker(K)=ker(S)$ and $ker(S)=\left\{0\right\}$ it follows $L^2([0,1])=\overline{\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,...)}$. And that means that $\left\{v_j\right\}$ is ONB of $L^2([0,1])$. I already showed that this is an ONS but how can i show that this is an ONB?

Comment: Was that a proof that $\left\{v_j\right\}$ is an ONB of $L^2([0,1])$ resp. $ker(S)^{\bot}$?

Comment: @math12 It was not. From the spectral theorem you know that the *complete* set of left-singular vectors is a basis for $L^2$. You did not prove that $v_j$ is a *complete* set of left-singular vectors. To do so, you should try to show that the linear span of $v_j$ is dense in $L^2$. Think of what you know about the density of trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: Sorry, but i never heard of the density of trigonometric polynomials. ;(

Comment: To sum up: I have to show 2 things: 1.) $\overline{span(v_j)}=ker(S)^{\bot}=L^2([0,1])$ and 2.) $\overline{span(u_j)}=\overline{rg(S)}=L^2([0,1])$ - right? How can I do that and why is $\overline{rg(S)}=L^2([0,1])$ ??

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to end this exchange here. It's been going on for too long already. You need to know some functional analysis to do this exercise. I can't teach it here from scratch. For example, it's a basic fact about adjoints that $\overline{\operatorname{range}(S)}=(\operatorname{ker} S^*)^\perp $

Comment: Okay, but in my readings it was not mentioned. No i only have to know why $\overline{span(v_j)}=L^2([0,1])$ resp. $\overline{span(u_j)}=L^2([0,1])$.